# sqlQuery giving error

Tags: sql, r

When I am trying to run the following query in R it is not working whereas the same query in working in sql

```
Vol_Traded <- sqlQuery(dbConnect, paste('select BusinessDate,sum(sales)sales from data
where A.BusinessDate >= '2016-02-05' and ID = 533177 
and DATENAME(dw, BusinessDate) NOT IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday')
group by BusinessDate
order by BusinessDate'))
```

The error I was getting in the output was:

> "[RODBC] ERROR : Could not SQLExecDirect "

Comment: Use `"` for strings like "Saturday", and use `'` to wrap the whole sql statement.

Comment: The error i was getting in the output was "[RODBC] ERROR : Could not SQLExecDirect "

Answer (score 0):

Does using double quotes for the string in R work?

```
Vol_Traded <- sqlQuery(dbConnect, paste("select BusinessDate, sum(sales) as sales from data
where A.BusinessDate >= '2016-02-05' and ID = 533177 
and DATENAME(dw, BusinessDate) NOT IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday')
group by BusinessDate
order by BusinessDate"))
```

My guess is that the only problem is the issue of the quotes.

Comment: Nothing worked so far. sorry not even with the double quotes. if i remove 2nd and 3rd line from the code it works but gives me all the data whereas i want the data with those date conditions